# BCL.XPRB dll isn't initializing in C#.Net application

Tags: c#, .net, initialization, base-class-library

I am trying to resolve an initialization error for the optimizer library. I have a license for and installed Xpress-IVE 64bit studio, however, I need to link and use xprb facilities in a C#.Net application that is built in VS2010 and runs on IIS.

I copied xprb.dll and xprbdn.dll to application bin folder for deployment, and added them as references.  Yet when the application calls XPRB.init(), it throws exception

```
    Unable to load DLL 'xprb.dll': The specified module could not be found. 
    (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
```

Any suggestions on what could be missing?

Comment: The error doesn't say that the DLL is missing, but that it's there but missing the right module.  I have looked at running the ProcMon but there are a couple of problems: the error happens on deployment site, where I can't run in debug mode, and also it's a Web app that runs on IIS, rather than out of an exe.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be a Windows/.Net/general instability issue.  The license, although installed, wasn't found by .Net, which decided to blow up as if the dll wasn't available.  Finally was resolved mysteriously after a few system reboots and updates.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but running windows 8.1, xpress-ive 64bit and vs2013 with c#. I could run IVE and solve problems from there, but i got "An unhandled exception of type 'Additional information: Unable to load DLL 'xprb.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)" error in runtime when running using bcl in VS. What solved the problem in my case was going through the necessary environment variables and directing them to the correct xpress folders (environment variables xpress, path and mosel.dso).